# How do you create a search bar like pinterest?

Tags: php, css, forms, search, categories

https://kimvij.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/new-interest-icons-plus-featured.png

As you can see in the above image, you can select a category in which you can search.  I know can create a search form with a select dropdown that has categories, but the thing is "select" dropdowns are hard to style with css and I wanted to make my own custom button with similar dropdown as pinterest.

The only other method I can think of is using "ul li" to get the values and style the drop down. My question for that is, will I still be able to get the input values of it if I use "ul li" within the form? For eg.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="search">
 <ul id="dropdown">
  <li id="category-1"></li>
  <li id="category-2"></li>
  <li id="category-3"></li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

if not, what's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the `li` value from a form. You can do this two way.
You can design your own menu with custom styling.

---

1. If you are going to do this via `ajax` then use `jQuery` to add a class to the selected `li` and retrive the same before submitting.
2. If you are using `php` to submit then I suggest you use a `hidden` field and use `jQuery` to change the value inside the `hidden` field after each selection takes place

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I will do that.  Thanks.